# "did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping" Error in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure Devops i tried to copy + paste one script in the yaml file. i got the syntax error "did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping".

I tried different ways by modifying script, changing indentation, modifying spaces. But nothing worked.

Comment: Finally, i have done some analysis & one solution is working for me. I am excited to share  with you.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than copy + paste, we need to type it manually with proper indentation is working for me.

Comment: you managed to find it out yourselves I see, thanks for letting us know!

Comment: you managed to find it out yourselves I see, thanks for letting us know!

Answer (score 0):

Indentation is very strict in YAML, please TAB carefully and try validators like:

https://www.yamllint.com/

https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator

Of course the AzDo editor can validate as well, but the external one sometimes are more helpful.
[image]